# Refinery CMS not installing on Rails3.2.6 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I've added gem `refinerycms`, `~> 2.0.10` in my existing rails app built with rails version 3.2.6 but when I run "bundle command" I'm getting this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    refinerycms-core (>= 0) ruby depends on
      jquery-rails (~> 2.0.0) ruby
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
```

I've tried with this below syntax:

```
git 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git' do
  gem 'refinerycms-core' #You can leave this out if you like. It's a dependency of the other engines.
  gem 'refinerycms-dashboard'
  gem 'refinerycms-images'
  gem 'refinerycms-pages'
  gem 'refinerycms-resources'
end
```

but still getting this error. How can Integrate `Refinery CMS` with my existing rails3.2.6 app?

Comment: Try to install the jquery-rails 2.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

This version of Refinery requires Rails 3.2.12/3.2.13 and your version of jquery-rails is not yet supported. Please specify versions that match the requirements here https://rubygems.org/gems/refinerycms-core#runtime_dependencies

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":   In Gemfile:
    refinerycms-core (>= 0) ruby depends on
      jquery-rails (~> 2.0.0) ruby
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
```

Do what it says and put this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.0.0'
```